# Why does this code keeping giving me this error? I am just trying to understand the raw bitcoin protocol

Tags: address, private-key, wallet-import-format

```
import random

def privateCeiToWif(Cei_hex) :
     return utils.base58CheckEncode(0x80, Cei_hex.decode('hex'))

def privateCeiTopublicCei(s) :
# secp256k1 : Standards for Efficient Cryptography (SEC)(Certicom Research) refers to the parameters of the ECDSA curve
    Signature = ecdsa.SigningCei.from_string(s.decode('hex'), curve = ecdsa.SECP256k1)
    verification = Signature.verifying_Cei
    return ('\04' + Signature.verifying_Cei.to_string()) .encode('hex')

def pubCeiToaddr(s) :
    ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    ripemd160.update(hashlib.sha256(s.decode('hex')).digest())
    return utils.base58CheckEncode(0, ripemd160.digest())

def CeiToaddr (s) :
    return pubCeiToaddr(privateCeiTopublicCei(s))

#WARNING :  This random function is not secure
private_Cei = ' '.join(['%x ' %random.randrange(16) for x  in range(0, 64)])
print CeiUtils.privateCeiToWif(private_Cei)
print CeiUtils.CeiToaddr(private_Cei)
```

[image: error message ceiutils]

Answer (score 1):

In python, you don't need to prefix a call to a function in the same module with the module's name. You can call it like `print privateCeiToWif(private_Cei)`

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RO0d.png I got this error after trying your solution

Comment: What do you expect that to call?